# Constraining values of non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'm trying to introduce a check where a non-type template parameter for a class is smaller than some maximum. Currently I have the following code which compiles:

```
template<std::size_t Size>
requires (Size < SIZE_MAXIMUM)
class arena_allocator
{
...
```

I have the following concept:

```
template<std::size_t Size> concept allocation_size =
requires{
    Size < SIZE_MAXIMUM;
};
```

When applying the concept as follows:

```
template<allocation_size Size>
class arena_allocator
{
...
```

I get the following error: `error C7600: 'hp::mem::allocation_size': the concept designated by a type constraint shall be a type concept`

Based on this I would guess that constraining non-type template parameters isn't possible using concepts, or am I missing something? If not, how would I constrain the values of a non-type template parameter?

Comment: note: the concept `requires {Size < SIZE_MAXIMUM;}` only check the expression is valid.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the distinction, it checks if the expression is valid, it doesn't check if the result of that expression equals true?

Comment: yes, it should be `concept allocation_size = Size < SIZE_MAXIMUM;`

Comment: @YSC yes the `requires(...)` is correct, but the `requires{...}` is not